# Why is this react-django app not rendering anything

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django

my App.js is in appname/src/components :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>This is the App.js</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
render(<App />, appDiv);
```

My index.js in appname/src:

```
import App from "./components/App";

const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, appDiv);
```

why is the server not rendering anything?

see my templates app name index.html in appname/templates/appname seems to be doing just fine:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Testing DJREACT with Yarn</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="app"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="{% static 'frontend/main.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I think I did the installation correctly. The title of the web is indeed getting rendered but the body is not.

console in the browser is showing this errors:
127.0.0.1/:9

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

127.0.0.1/:15

```
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/frontend/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: I think the issue is because I create the static folder inside an app of my project?  Can this be the bug??